# Limitations/Drawbacks of web application development with node js mongodb and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

It is quite common that people develop highly scalable and high-performance sites/web applications with node JS, mongodb on the back end and angularJS on the front end.

Can anyone give pros and cons for developing web based solutions with these technologies?

Comment: @chridam If the vote is to close please could you help me as I spent some time answering this question yesterday in order to help this guy out along with anybody else who would like the opinion of somebody with 10+ experience years in webdev who has worked on sites with over 30m uniques pm and web applications using frameworks extensively. Granted I don't have refs in my answer and this is largely based opinion and experience but please either help to edit the question/answer or don't close it. I came into SO a bit late in my career so don't have many points. Please help a guy, thanks. :)

Comment: @JohnnyHK ? please comment

Answer (score 4):

Web based solution is a very broad term. For both the front and back end tech choice it all depends on:

1. The knowledge of your existing team
2. Your target audience, B2B or B2C (i.e. how much you can dictate browser support... applies more to the front end)
3. Your budget
4. Which ties in with your time to deliver and required release cycle
5. The performance of your solution

Note that a high-performance site and a web application are two very different things, however unfortunately bad practice out there of people generally wanting to use tech for the sake of it (generally for their own learning sake over the benefit of the product), the line between the two it blurring.

A high-performance site with large concurrency is best suited to an appropriate back end heavy solution. There are arguments all over the web about which is best but perf tests to my knowledge suggest that node is very good but other languages can out perform it. However performance isn't *everything* as per my tradeoffs above.

A web app (say a single page app or SPA) is best built with client side heavy tech that is really in tune with the back end and apis. If your team is small and you all have good JS knowledge then it might make sense to use node with a JS framework (such as Angular, or React or the like) or an all encompassing front and back end solution such as [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/).

Angular is really powerful, comes with testing mocks for you and allows really rapid development (took me a week to learn, having no prior knowledge of frameworks, but solid JS knowledge, I just read the entire manual) but in my experience falls short of building **really large** client side apps out the box.

There are only serious Drawbacks with using them if they aren't right for your solution in some way. You may find this later down the line after picking any one tech but that comes down to experience, knowledge and asking questions. Maybe supply more info and you might get less of a generic answer from me :)

p.s. I wasn't the idiot who downvoted your question without the decency of an edit or a comment :)

Comment: Thanks alexrogins. Your suggestions are deeply appreciated :)

Comment: Unable to vote as it requires 15 reputation. This answer is correct.

Comment: A stupid SO limitation IMO. You have 15